# How to prevent direct access to cert files when connecting MQTT client with Python

Tags: python, security, mqtt, tls1.2

I am using the pho MQTT client library successfully to connect to AWS. After the mqtt client is created, providing the necessary keys and certificates is done with a call to client.tls_set() This method requires file paths to root certificate, own certificate and private key file.

All is well and life is good except that I now need to provide this code to external contractors whom should not have direct access to these cert and key files. The contractors have a mix of PC and macOS systems. On macOS we have keychain I am familiar with but do not know how to approach this with python - examples/library references would be great. On the PC I have no idea which is the prevalent mechanism to solve this.

To add to this, I have no control over the contractor PCs/Macs - i.e., I have no ability to revoke an item in their keychain. How do I solve this?

Sorry for being such a noob in security aspects. No need to provide complete examples, just references to articles to read, courses to follow and keywords to search would be great - though code examples will be happily accepted also of course.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't.

Longer answer:

If you want them to be able connect then you have no choice but to give them the cert/private key that identifies that device/user.

The control you have is issue each contractor with their own unique key/cert and if you believe key/cert has been miss used, revoke the cert at the CA and have the broker check the revocation list.

You can protect the private key with a password, but again you have to either include this in the code or give it to the contractor.

Even if the contractors were using a device with a hardware keystore (secure element) that you could securely store the private key in, all that would do is stop the user from extracting the key and moving it to a different machine, they would still be able to make use of the private key for what ever they want on that machine.

The best mitigation is to make sure the certificate has a short life and control renewing the certificate, this means if a certificate is leaked then it will stop working quickly even if you don't notice and explicitly revoke it.

Comment: I was afraid of this but ok, revoking the certs it is then. Thanks for clearing this up for me